# List all collections from a mongodb with POCO C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, poco-libraries

I try to get all available collections from a MongoDB using POCO C++ driver. But I haven't found anything on web and tried using the `createCommand()` with `selector("$query").add("listCollections", 1)` without any success. It seems POCO does not have an implementation for querying all collections inside a db or does anybody know how to do this?

MongoDB driver itself has a command like `getCollectionNames()` but I can not find this inside POCO.

I tried using this snippet:

```
Poco::MongoDB::Database db("db_name");
    auto command = db.createCommand();
    command->selector().addNewDocument("$query").add("listCollections", 1);
Poco::MongoDB::ResponseMessage resp;
DBCONN.sendRequest(*command, resp);
```

I get a document back with:
Content: `{"ok":0,"errmsg":"no such cmd: listCollections","bad cmd":{"$query":{"listCollections":1}}}`

Comment: Is there a reason your are using the POCO MongoDB C++ driver (of which I was only vaguely aware), rather than either the official C driver or official C++ driver? The POCO driver looks like it is missing a ton of features.

Comment: I changed to the official C++ driver at there it works. I also detected that on server side the MongoDB Version 2.4.10 was running and updated it to latest version After update also the Poco driver as listed above shows me the expected result. Nevertheless i continue to use the official driver because it seems this one is faster as the Poco implementation.